# html/jquery .mask organinzing phone number

Tags: jquery, mask

i'm using:

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.maskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery(function($){
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999", {placeholder:" "});
});
</script>
```

I don't know if i'm overlooking something simple or what or maybe i did the html stuff wrong:

```
Phone number: <input type="text" id="phone" name="phoneNumber"/>
```

My objective is to make it look like (999) 999-9999 with hidden ext. 999 if they don't need it. but the whole script isn't working or doing anything at all.

Comment: What you mean with "hidden ext. 999"? if the user only enters 7 digits hide the (999) part?

Comment: like they only have to enter 7 digits it doesn't make them enter and extension if they don't need one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the placeholder section.

Just add

```
$("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999? x99999");
```

**EDIT**

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrodriguezr/4CVC6/)

Comment: What maskedinput version are you using? Check out the EDIT section (jsfiddle added)

Comment: i got the code from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/#demo sooo whatever there using....ok i may have totally overlooked this but i've never used jquery, are you supposed to download something along with this code?

Comment: yup that was it. that was totally dumb of me. thanks for getting me on the right track

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById('kisicep_telefonu').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : '(' + x[1] + ') ' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '-' + x[3] : '');
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group form-material col-md-6" data-plugin="formMaterial">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="kisicep_telefonu">Cep Telefonunuz</label>
  <span class="required" style="color:red">*</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="kisicep_telefonu" name="kisicep_telefonu" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="(000) 000-0000 ">
</div>
```